# Is this an isomorphism for $D_8$?

Tags: galois-theory, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product, direct-product

Given the $20^{th}$ primitive root of unity $\omega$, we know that it's splitting field is  $\Bbb Q(\omega)$.  Furthermore we know that it's a Galois extension and that it's minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ is $x^8-x^6+x^4-x^2+1$, which had degree 8 , so the Galois group has degree 8. We can also see this from the fact that the roots of the minimal polynomial are exactly those powers of $\omega$ which are coprime to $20$. From this second fact We can deduce that the Galois group must be isomorphic to $\Bbb U_{20} \cong\Bbb U_5\times\Bbb U_4 \cong C_4\times C_2$.

This implies that the structure of the group is going to consist of transpositions and 4 cycles.

We in fact know that each automorphism will be of the form $\phi_k:\omega\rightarrow \omega ^k$ where $k$ is coprime to, and less than, $n $.

So we can list the automorphisms explicitly as :

$e:\omega \rightarrow \omega$

$\phi_2:\omega \rightarrow \omega^3$

$\phi_3:\omega \rightarrow \omega^9$

$\phi_4:\omega \rightarrow \omega^7$

$\phi_5:\omega \rightarrow \omega^{11}$

$\phi_1:\omega \rightarrow \omega^{13}$

$\phi_6:\omega \rightarrow \omega^{19}$

$\phi_7:\omega \rightarrow \omega^{17}$

These ,respectively, correspond exactly to how the elements of $D_8=\langle r,s|r^4=s^2=1 ,s^{-1}rs=r^{-1} \rangle$ would act. Which leads me to believe that the group is isomorphic to $D_8$. But here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product in the examples of the  outer semi direct product section it says that $D_{2n}$ isomorphic to a semidirect product of the cyclic groups $C_n$ and $C_2$, while in this case we only have a direct product? What is happening here , the structures are identical I believe, yet it seems we don't have the conditions for isomorphism? I know I must be wrong about one of those things.

Comment: Why do you think they behave like $D_{8}$?

Comment: The structures are identical? You mean $D_8$ and $C_4\times C_2$? One is abelian and the other isn't.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I realised that I miscalculated how $\phi_7$ acts, (I hadn't thought about the abelian property) . I see now they're not the same..  I think I may have made a mistake about the automorphisms aswell , I think what I stated above is just true for $C_n$ , is that correct ?

Comment: The automorphisms seem right though I haven’t looked in detail. And I think those just form the group $C_4\times C_2$. I’m not sure what you’re referring to as true for $C_n.$